# Vacation/Antisocial mode: block incoming call, notification and internet acccess to selected app

Tags: android

I'm looking for an app that I can quickly toggle to go in an "antisocial" mode that:

- block internet access and notification for selected app (WhatsApp,
  Gmail, ...)
- block incoming call & SMS

There is a lot of app for "Digital Detox", but it's not what I want. I'm OK with my phone usage. I want to block "other people", not myself.

In the past I was using the airplane mode. But recently I'm using my phone as an hotspot so airplane mode is not an option anymore.

I also don't want the phone to be "blocked", as I may need to quickly check for a phone number or my calendar.

I do not want a paternalist app that does not allow me to open an app or show me stats about my usage. Blocking internet access to selected app is enough (I want to be able to still use them offline).

It should be simple:

- A way to select the app I want to block
- A checkbox to block SMS/Call
- Toggle antisocial mode (On/Off)
- When on, it should clear all notification and add himself as a notification: "antisocial is on, press to switch off".

My phone is a samsung galaxus a3 (2017) running android 8.0.0. I'm using the [KISS launcher](https://kisslauncher.com/). Last, I do not want to have to root my phone.

Comment: Which device and version of Android OS are you using?

Comment: @MorrisonChang samsung galaxus a3 (2017)  with android 8.0.0 and KISS as a launcher.

Comment: You can probably use Tasker for this.

Comment: @janot I taught about it, I'm using Automate (similar to tasker) already to switch on the hotspot when I'm arriving at home an plug my phone. I will look into that when I got some time. But perhaps I will take the time to do the app I want.